# Antispam for telegram bot

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on creating a telegram bot, I want to make an anti-spam system, that is, when a person presses a button too many times, the bot will freeze for him for a certain number of seconds, it is possible to write a message about blocking. I just started learning JavaScript.
I use node-telegram-bot-api.

```
import {
    bot
} from '../token.js';

import {
    keyboardMain
} from '../keyboards/keyboardsMain.js';

export function commands() {
    bot.on('message', msg => {
        const text = msg.text;
        const chatId = msg.chat.id;

        if (text === '/start') {
           return bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'hello', keyboardMain);
        }

        return bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'error');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. What had been your current current approaches? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user throttler using Javascript Map

```
/*
 * @param {number} waitTime Seconds to wait
 */
function throttler(waitTime) {
  const users = new Map()
  return (chatId) => {
     const now = parseInt(Date.now()/1000)
     const hitTime = users.get(chatId)
     if (hitTime) {
       const diff = now - hitTime
       if (diff < waitTime) {
         return false
       } 
       users.set(chatId, now)
       return true
     }
     users.set(chatId, now)
     return true
  }
}
```

How to use: You'll get the user's chatId from telegram api. You can use that id as an identifier and stop the user for given specific time.

For instance I'm gonna stop the user for 10seconds once the user requests.

```
// global 10 second throttler
const throttle = throttler(10) // 10 seconds

// in your code
const allowReply = throttle(chatId) // chatId obtained from telegram

if (allowReply) {
   // reply to user
} else {
  // dont reply
}
```

Comment: But how does it work? Where do I need to put my data? I do not understand